# Can a pulsar also be a magnetar?

Tags: astrophysics, neutron-star, terminology, pulsar, magnetar

I know this is a simplistic question, but I cannot find a straight answer...

Also, is it possible most or all neutron stars are magnetars and/or pulsars?  It's just hard to see all of their properties from our vantage point, etc.?

Comment: magnetars are only a small special case fraction of neutron stars, but are all magnetars also pulsars, hmmm.... Nice article (and video) here but no explicit sentences saying that. https://phys.org/news/2016-08-magnetars.html I don't know if a "pulsar" is something that is *observed in some way* to pulse, or if its any rotating strongly magnetized object *likely* to pulse, that would be expected to pulse if one were to measure it.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsar#Categories) magnetars are one of the 3 categories of pulsars. It's not easy to detect a neutron star if it's not a pulsar, and if the beam doesn't sweep the Earth. OTOH, I suppose we may be able to see non-beamed radiation if the neutron star has an active accretion disk, or if the beam creates a tell-tale signature in a nearby gas cloud.

Comment: Also, from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star There are thought to be around one billion neutron stars in the Milky Way [...] However, most are old and cold and radiate very little; most neutron stars that have been detected occur only in certain situations in which they do radiate, such as if they are a pulsar or part of a binary system. Slow-rotating and non-accreting neutron stars are almost undetectable.

Answer (score 2):

[Magnetars](https://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/M/Magnetar) are the most widely-accepted explanations for two observed classes of objects:

- [Soft gamma repeaters](https://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/S/Soft+Gamma+Repeater) (SGRs)
- [Anomalous X-ray pulsars](https://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/A/Anomalous+X-ray+Pulsar) (AXPs)

Under the magnetar hypothesis, these classes of objects are explained as highly magnetised neutron stars, evolving from a soft gamma repeater (expected lifetime ~10000 years) to an anomalous X-ray pulsar (expected lifetime ~10000 years) as the rotation period lengthens and the magnetic field decays.

The AXPs are pulsars, and at least some SGRs have been identified with pulsars (e.g. [Sgr 0526-26 = PSR B0525-26](https://simbad.harvard.edu/simbad/sim-id?Ident=PSR%20B0525-66&NbIdent=1&Radius=2&Radius.unit=arcmin&submit=submit%20id)). So under the magnetar hypothesis, magnetars can indeed be pulsars.

It's worth noting that the magnetar hypothesis may not explain (all?) SGRs and AXPs: there does seem to be evidence that some of these objects do not have especially strong magnetic fields compared to pulsars, e.g. SGR 0418+5729 ([Rea et al. 2010](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010Sci...330..944R/abstract)), and there have been suggestions that some of these objects may actually be white dwarfs ([Lobato et al. 2016](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016IJMPD..2541025L/abstract)), perhaps somewhat similar to the [white dwarf pulsar](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2017NatAs...1E..29B/abstract) in AR Scorpii.

Answer (score 1):

Magnetars are a type of pulsar and pulsars are a type of neutron star. So all magnetars are neutron stars, but some neutron stars are not pulsars, and some pulsars are not magnetars.

[image]

However, neutron stars that aren't pulsars are [very difficult to observe](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/34390/9527).  And even among the pulsars, there are only  [12% of them that we can actually see](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/36047/9527).

Comment: You have misunderstood something. Nowhere near as many as 12% of neutron stars are pulsars. I would think it is somewhere between 1 in 1000 to 1 in 10000.

Comment: The ATNF pulsar catalogue contains about 3000 pulsars. If we assume these represent the 10% that can be observed because of a small beam width, then there are more like 30,000 pulsars. But there are expected to be a billion neutron stars in the Galaxy. Maybe my 1 in 10,000 is too big; I'm not sure how complete the ATNF catalogue will be.

Comment: A better way is to note that the lifetime of the pulsar phenomenon is about 1-10 million years. Even if pulsars are born at a constant rate then there would be 1000-10,000 times as many "dead" pulsars.

Comment: To add to what Rob said, the beaming fraction isn't the fraction of neutron stars which are pulsars, but the fraction of pulsars which are observable as pulsars to us.

Comment: "Pulsars are a type of neutron star." This is not strictly true, AR Scorpii shows that occasionally white dwarfs can be pulsars.